# How to I get all the log messages for the last week for a given file in git?

Tags: git, logging, git-log

I want to list all the commits against a specific file for the last week.

Comment: WTF? What's wrong with that question?

Answer (score 1):

Wow! It's easier than I thought!

git log  --since="1 week ago"  -- the/file/I.want